# eslint destructuring coming as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eslint, destructuring

I have a component and corresponding actions and reducers for it.
In actions, when I am doing the API call, I make the call like this

```
    export const getData = () => {
     return axios.post(url, data, headers){
               .then((response)=>{
                  const messages = response.data.map({has_favourited_message: isFavourited}) //I am doing this since ESLINT throws errors
=>({isFavourited})
    })
    return messages;
     }
    }
```

In the component, I am using it like this

```
class ProductView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { page: 0, imageUrls: [], isFavourited: props.product.isFavourited || props.product['has_favourited_message']
  }
render(){
  return null;
}
}
```

In the reducer, I have

```
case GET_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: state.data.map((item) => {
          if (item.id !== action.payload.id) return item;
          return { ...state, ...item, has_favourited_message: action.payload.isFavourited }; //Here I don't want to add any extra key so I am using the original key only as I am dispatch the above action to multiple reducers so it would become inconsistent if I change the key
        }),
      };
```

I am using `props.product.isFavourited || props.product.'has_favourited_message'` because ES-Lint won't allow me to use like this ------ `props.product['has_favourited_message']`.
I believe that there is a better way of doing this without changing the key in reducer or adding comment eslint-disable-line.

I am new to desructuring. Please help.

Comment: It throws ESlint issues

Comment: What warning does it show for `props.product['has_favourited_message']`? That surprises me.

Comment: It gives error that props.product['has_favourited_message'] should be better written with dot notation. @Andy

Comment: Which would be `props.product.has_favourited_message` not `props.product.'has_favourited_message'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check if property is present or not by ***hasOwnProperty('property1')***
Later you can use

```
props.product.hasOwnProperty('has_favourited_message') ?props.product.has_favourited_message : 'There is no favourited message'
```

I hope i would help

Answer (score 0):

You map function syntax is incorrect, you need a wrapping `()` before destructuring map arguments

```
.then((response)=>{                     
     const messages = response.data.map(({has_favourited_message: isFavourited}) => ({isFavourited})
     return messages;
 })
```

Also instead of `props.product.'has_favourited_message'`, you should write `props.product.has_favourited_message` since `props.product.'has_favourited_message'` is an invalid syntax

Comment: sorry, I missed that in my question. It's written just like the answer that you've suggested but my question is something else